# Improved First Fit

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I am working on different heuristic solutions for the bin packing problem and have implemented different algorithms such as FF, FFD, BF, BFD and so on. My question is, is there any better algorithm than these or is there any (even small) improvements on these algorithms. I have read a lot and searched for this but could not find something really interesting.

Comment: I believe first fit is as optimal as it gets.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) mentions MFFD which may be worth looking into.

Comment: First Fit (Decreasing) does not find the optimal result. In cloud balancing it's 14% worse, in nurse rostering it's up to 70% worse. See my [benchmark slides](http://www.optaplanner.org/learn/slides.html) for more numbers.

Comment: Hello again. Thank you for your answers. I will work on MFFD and try to understand Geoffrey De Smet benchmark results. I think they will be really interesting. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I use construction heuristics (such as FF, FFD, BF, BFD) followed by metaheuristics (such as Tabu Search, Simulated Annealing, Late Acceptance) in [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) (java, open source) to get better results than just FFD:

[image]

Comment: I think it is really what I am looking for. But first of all I have to find out which metaheuristics there exists and how they work. If I have question I will disturb again :) Did you work on the offline Bin packing or you have made also some measurements in the online bin packing field?